# Keyboard does not work as expected with input type number

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have implemented a register activity which contains fragments in a viewpager. In one of this fragments, I have a form with some EditText created dinamically. 
The problem is that if I set the input type number or phone to one of this EditText then the keyboard stops inputing numbers.
If I set input type to text then it works as expected.

Here is the code where I set the input types:

```
switch(mDatosSocio.getTipo()){
                case "text":
                    etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS);
                    break;
                case "number":
                    etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
                    break;
                case "email":
                    etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Any ideas about that? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
**Solution**

The problem was that I had this function in the parent activity so it was preventing the input of numbers.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("KEYDOWN", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    }
    else if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("KEYUP", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    }
    Log.d("KEY", event.getKeyCode()+"");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply additional option TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL.

```
etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)
```

**Edited:**

Here is my example code, and tested in Galaxy S7 with reference keyboard app.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    EditText editText1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.real_edittext);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/real_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still no luck :(

Comment: What kind keyboard app do you using now? Works fine with Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: I have tested it on Nexus 5x, Samsung Galaxy Tab A6 and Leotec Argon e250. It seems that there is something wrong with my code.
With                     etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
 i can't write numbers either.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the setTipo() of the mDatosSocio. String comparison may be wrong due to typos.

Comment: Tipos are correct. I have tried different keyboards.
If I use samsung keyboard i can write numbers but I can't delete. In contrast, if I use google keyboard I can't use numbers :|

Comment: Could you resolve this? I am facing a similar issue on my Pixel device on Android P. I am upgrading the app to target API version 28. It does not happen otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Add like this and check

```
EditText etFormField= new EditText(context);
etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); //for decimal numbers
etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED); //for positive or negative values
```

In your case probably like this

```
etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Or else like this also you can try for specific type of input type values

```
etFormField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE );
```

Comment: Still no luck with these three combinations :( Phone keyboard is shown but the only character I can input is the dot but no numbers. Very strange...